# ASP.NET how to get the currently logged in users name and ID from a SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I am currently still a junior programmer and have taken over from a previous programmer and i am busy carrying on with his ASP.NET website. He has created his own login and i cant figure out how to display the currently logged in user into a ReadOnly Textbox.

The reason the textBox is readonly is because once a user has logged onto the website any data that is inserted into the SQL database gets added with the currently logged in userID but for Convenience the User name is shown in a readOnly textBox.

here is the Code for the login.aspx

```
protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        LoggedMember member = new LoggedMember();

        if (LoginUser.UserName.Contains('@'))
        {
            member = Login.LogInContact(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password);
        }
        else
        {
            member = Login.LogInUser(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password);
        }

        if (member.ID != 0)
        {
            Session["LoggedMember"] = member;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(member.UserName, true);
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("~/pages/Monitor.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["LoggedMember"] = null;
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }

    }
```

LoggedMember Class

```
public class LoggedMember
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Login Class

```
public class Login
{
    public static LoggedMember LogInUser(string username, string password)
    {
        LoginContext db = new LoginContext();

        User user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password).SingleOrDefault();

        LoggedMember member = new LoggedMember();
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.UserID != 0)
            {
                member = new LoggedMember()
                {
                    ID = user.UserID,
                    UserName = user.UserName
                };
            }
        }

        if (user != null)
        {
            member.Profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfileAndSettings((int)user.UserProfileID);
        }
        else
        {
            member.Profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfileAndSettings(0);
        }
        return member;
    }

    public static LoggedMember LogInContact(string username, string password)
    {
        LoginContext db = new LoginContext();

        Contact contact = db.Contacts.Where(u => u.Email == username && u.Password == password).SingleOrDefault();

        LoggedMember member = new LoggedMember();
        if (contact.ContactID != 0)
        {
            member = new LoggedMember()
            {
                ID = contact.ContactID,
                UserName = contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName
            };
        }

        return member;
    }
}
```

How would i go about loading the currently logged in userName into the ReadOnly textBox and once a record is added to the database to get the userID of the currently logged in user.

I am using C#,Sql server and linq

Thank you

Comment: Plain text password alert... somebody needs shooting (hint: it is a *really* bad idea to store passwords, **even encrypted**; you should *salt+hash* them instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple just assigning `username` to `TextBox` like

```
Textbox1.Text = username;
```

For getting the `UserID` of the `Current Login User` you need to call a `select query` like

```
Select UserId from tablename where username = "Pass username";
```

Your `username` must be unique otherwise you wil get multiple `UserId` from this query.

You need to use this type of scenario.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Since the login code sets a forms-auth cookie, you should be able to use:

```
public static string GetUsername() {
    var ident = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    return ident.IsAuthenticated ? ident.Name : null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i set that to true just to test, it initially was false. Your code does work. But how am i able to access the UserID From the value that has been inserted into the textBox.

Because when i insert data into the SQL database i do not add user names, i insert userID's

Comment: @user2343291 to store composite values is more difficult; you can write a custom "principal", but that is complex; you could store the login name as "12345:fred" but that would require changes to any code that current accesses it. Perhaps simplest is just to cache the name=>id map in memory and *look it up*